# Calling ArrayAdapter causes infinite loop?

Tags: android, arraylist, infinite-loop, android-arrayadapter

In my app, I have an option to save an item to favourites. I save two ID's in an ArrayList. When a user calls favourites, it loops through the arraylist and for each item, I get the corresponding data from my database. The information I get back is again stored in an arraylist. I want to display this list in a Listview.

But the last step doesn't seem to work, as I'm in an infinite loop if I call my ListViewAdapter. I don't quite understand why. It will be something stupid, but I can't find what's wrong.

Here I loop through my first arralist with my ID's:

```
public void getJobs(){
    for(int i = 0; i<vaca.size(); i++){
        getVacatures(vaca.get(i), kantoor.get(i));
        arrVacature.add(vacature);
    }
}
```

Here I call my data from database:

```
 private void getVacatures(String vacaid, String kantoorid){
        try {
            Log.e("in try", "try");
            /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */

            URL url = new URL("http://172.21.150.140:80/scripts/cgiip.exe/WService=brAccentBe/Android/getFavorieten.p?vacaid="+vacaid+"&kantoorid=" + kantoorid);

            System.out.println("URL: "+ url);
            //URL url = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22409181/offices.xml");
            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
            favorietenWebService vs = new favorietenWebService();
            xr.setContentHandler(vs);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            /* Parsing has finished. */

            /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
            vacature = vs.getVacatures();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
```

Here I do a call to my adapter and will dismiss the dialog when the list is looped. This is where it goes wrong.

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        if (arrVacature.size() == 0){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        //for each time I loop this in debugger, it adds items to my ArrayList...WHY?
        if(arrVacature!=null && arrVacature.size() > 0){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i= 0; i< arrVacature.size();i++){
                adapter.add(arrVacature.get(i));
            }
            dialog.dismiss();

            TextView atlVacatures = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atlVacatures);
            TextView atlVacaturesnr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atlVacaturesnummer);
            atlVacaturesnr.setText("" + arrVacature.size());
            atlVacatures.setText(" jobs op maat gevonden!");

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

This is my adapter class (Note, getArray just returns my arrVacature array.):

```
private class VacatureFavoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vacature>{

    private ArrayList<Vacature> vacatures;


    public VacatureFavoAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Vacature> vacatures){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, vacatures);
        this.vacatures = getArray();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = convertview;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.vacature_list_item, null);
            //view.setBackgroundColor((position % 2) == 1? Color.LTGRAY: Color.WHITE);
        }

        Vacature vaca = vacatures.get(position);        

        if(vaca != null){               
            TextView tvNaam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vacatureNaam);
            TextView tvWerkveld = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vacatureWerkveld);
            TextView tvRegio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vacatureRegio);
        if(tvNaam != null){   

            tvNaam.setText(vaca.getTitel());
            if(tvWerkveld != null){
                tvWerkveld.setText("Werkveld: " + vaca.getWerkveld());
                if(tvRegio!=null){
                    tvRegio.setText("Regio: "+vaca.getRegio());
                }
            }
        }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line:

```
adapter.add(arrVacature.get(i));
```

An ArrayAdapter's `add()` method is used to add an item to whichever array has been assigned to back that ArrayAdapter. I assume that `adapter` is an instance of `VacatureFavoAdapter`. Therefore, when you call `adapter.add()`
you're adding `arrVacature.get(i)` to the array that backs the ArrayAdapter. How have you constructed `adapter`?

Also, I'm not totally sure why you're calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` twice.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. Aside from the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, where you have a point, I don't quite understand what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: OK. What is your code that you used to declare / construct `adapter`?

Comment: I do this in my onCreate method `this.adapter = new VacatureFavoAdapter(this, R.layout.vacature_list_item, arrVacature);
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);`

Comment: OK. So the list that you are using to back `adapter` is `arrVacature`. So whenever you call `adapter.add()`, I think that the ArrayAdapter adds the item back into `arrVacature`. (An ArrayAdapter does not make a copy of the list - it just keeps a reference to it.) So I think that your `adapter.add(arrVacature.get(i))` does the same as `arrVacature.add(arrVacature.get(i))`.

Comment: I think I'm following you, but I'm still not sure how to solve it. Should I make a new ArrayList?

Comment: It depends on exactly how you want your application to work (I'm not 100% sure I understand how you want your ArrayList to behave) but yes, to have a separate List that backs the ArrayList would be one possible solution. Another possible option, however, is to simply call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` without the need to perform an .add(), because the adapter will loop over arrVacature for you - because that's the list that you supplied when you constructed the adapter.

Comment: You have two options - add the items directly to your ArrayList and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter (in this case you do not need to add any items to the adapter), or create a new ArrayList and then add this to the existing adapter data by looping through it and calling `adapter.add()` on each item in the new list (you do not need to call `notifyDatasetChanged` in this case as the `adapter.add` method automatically calls it afterwards.)

Comment: Okay, I see it now! thank you very much! I've deleted the `adapter.add()`code and now it runs smoothly! Thank you so so much!